# Ways to identify a remote SSH servers Key Length

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am new to this SSH and Bash, I am trying to know a remote SSH servers configuration for debugging purposes for e.g. to know what ciphers, MAC's, Algorithms, and length of the key that is been used by a remote server without logging in just by establishing the connection through  my bash script using

```
$ ssh -vvv <>
```

with this command i am able to get details on ciphers, MACs, Key exchange algorithms but i am unable to find the length of the key, so similarly with a command i would like to find the length of the key without logging in to the remote server, if some one could walk me down this would be really helpful. Looking forwards, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Usually with `nmap` and `ssh-hostkey`

```
nmap host --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey=all
```

Maybe you need to install `nmap` first:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

<sub>More information [here](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html).</sub>

But there seems to be a bug in 15.04. The command works perfectly in 15.10.

Comment: Using nmap to find the hostkey would not be a elegant way because there are many cons in using nmap for such a simple task. Thanks anyways. 
Hope there will be an alternative to find the key length (Serverkeybits)

Comment: @sanjaysrikakulam: looks like a good one to me!  +1  And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**